# How to color text duplicates uniquely for each pair?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Will it be possible to color each pair (or more) of duplicates containing text from two columns in Google Sheets?

I'm using the following rule: `=COUNTIF($A$2:G,Indirect(Address(Row(),Column(),)))>1`
However, it highlights all duplicates with the same color

Comment: not possible without script

Comment: Where are you using Google Apps Script? If it's simply a conditional formatting formula, did you include the tag because you wish to use Google Apps Script as a more stable replacement for your formula?

Comment: @Geza OP didn't include it, but a editor included it because `not possible without script`(I agree)

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Do you know where such a script can be found?

Comment: @Seb Realistically, Someone would have to design it from scratch.